# Programming Chess in Functional programming

Tags: performance, functional-programming

A year ago I programmed a chess AI using the Alphabeta prunning algorithm. This was relatively straight forward to do in c++. One of the main issues I considered while doing this was making my code efficient. I did this by using having a data type I called a "game" that I passed around through the search tree made by the algorithm. To increase efficiency I didn't ever copy the "game" data type but rather mutated it while keeping the nessisary information needed to return it to its previous states.

Recently I have been reading about functional programming and the concept of purely using functions that do not change the state of the parameters they are passed appeals to me. I am wondering how I would using the paradigm of functional programming while still taking efficiency of the program into account.

In OOP the solution seems quite straight forward (which is what I implemented) while in functional programming it seems that copying data types is nessisary which decreases efficiency. Is it possible to use functional programming without this loss of efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional programming, data structures are not always copied completely. In many cases, only the part that changes needs to be copied, while the old parts can be referenced (since no mutation is allowed, this is safe).

The article on [persistant data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) describes this in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Jephron's answer points out the important fact that only small parts of a persistent data structure need to get updated, thus the bigger part is shared between the old state and the new state.

To be honest, this would still be slower than a mutation in most cases.

But immutable, persistent data structures have other advantages. Let's assume you have already completed the playing engine. And now, you want to implement a history (for example to allow the player to undo earlier moves). This is dead simple: Just remember all states in a list. You'll find that you need to touch only a few functions to take a list of states instead of just the last state, and you're done. You don't need to worry about compromising your game engine --- there is no global variable or something you could destroy.

Another thing is taking advantage of the many CPU cores you probably have by employing parallelism. Needless to say that you can't let many tasks, threads, fibers or whatever operate on a single mutable data structure. This would just become a synchronization nightmare, and your code would probably go slower even. However, there simply are no synchronization problems on immutable data, as they are read only for all threads.
This could very well speed up your code in such a way that it dwarfs the C++ solution, even if "doing a move" on a functional data structure is much slower than on mutable data.

Here is an example for changing a board game (TTT) from single threaded to parallel: https://dierk.gitbooks.io/fregegoodness/content/src/docs/asciidoc/incremental_episode4.html